# Viewing node-editor-created project on 3D view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, node-editor

I created a blend file which is sun lens flare created in Cycles render. I can access the lens flare in node editor but not in the 3D view's rendered mode. Can anyone tell me how to view it on 3D view mode? Or if it's just created in node editor so it can only be viewed in node editor? Thanks!

Comment: Compositing result cannot be seen from 3D View. However, if the output node type is Composite, Viewer or Split Viewer, you can view it in UV/Image Editor (as "Render Result" or "Viewer Node").

Comment: How do I use the created sun lens flare to another project like copying it or something like that?